# Unable to setup gtkmm

Tags: c++, gtk, installation, gtkmm

I am trying to setup gtkmm on my Windows 7 system. I have installed Glade 3.6.1 and gtkmm Development Environment 2.22.0-2.

When I tried to run the sample code below, I am unable to compile and run.

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);

    Gtk::Window window;

    Gtk::Main::run(window);

    return 0;
}
```

The compile log:

> Compiler: Default compiler Building Makefile:
>   "C:\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win" Executing  make... make.exe -f
>   "C:\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win" main.o g++.exe -c main.cpp -o main.o
>   -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"  -mms-bitfields -IC:/GTK/include/gtkmm-2.4 -IC:/GTK/lib/gtkmm-2.4/include -IC:/GTK/include/atkmm-1.6 -IC:/GTK/include/giomm-2.4 -IC:/GTK/lib/giomm-2.4/include -IC:/GTK/include/pangomm-1.4 -IC:/GTK/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -IC:/GTK/include/gtk-2.0 -IC:/GTK/include/gdkmm-2.4 -IC:/GTK/lib/gdkmm-2.4/include -IC:/GTK/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4 -IC:/GTK/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -IC:/GTK/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/GTK/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/GTK/include/sigc++-2.0 -IC:/GTK/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -IC:/GTK/include/cairomm-1.0 -IC:/GTK/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -IC:/GTK/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/GTK/include/cairo -IC:/GTK/include -IC:/GTK/include/freetype2 -IC:/GTK/include/libpng14 -IC:/GTK/lib/gtk-2.0/include -IC:/GTK/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/GTK/include/libglademm-2.4
>
> In file included from
>   C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/containerhandle_shared.h:24,
>                    from C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/arrayhandle.h:23,
>                    from C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm.h:82,
>                    from C:/GTK/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm.h:87,
>                    from main.cpp:1: C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:861: error: ISO C++ forbids
>   declaration of `wostringstream' with no type
>   C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:861: error: expected`;'
>   before "StreamType" C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:865:
>   error: `StreamType' does not name a type
>
> C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:906: error: expected
>   constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '&' token
>   C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:906: error: expected `,' or`
>   ;' before '&' token C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:912:
>   error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '&'
>   token C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:912: error: expected
>   `,' or`;' before '&' token
>
> C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h: In member function `void
>   Glib::ustring::FormatStream::stream(const T&)':
>   C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:1057: error:`stream_'
>   undeclared (first use this function)
>   C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:1057: error: (Each
>   undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it
>   appears in.)
>
> C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h: In member function `void
>   Glib::ustring::FormatStream::stream(const char*)':
>   C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:1063: error:`stream_'
>   undeclared (first use this function)
>   C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h: In member function `void
>   Glib::ustring::FormatStream::stream(char*)':
>   C:/GTK/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:1069: error:`stream_'
>   undeclared (first use this function)
>
> make.exe: *** [main.o] Error 1
>
> Execution terminated

Any help with the setup would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This may be a bug in gtkmm Window$ support, try a web-search or check the mailing lists. If I'm not mistaken, gtkmm has some problems on Windows so check that before you investigate further. If it indeed has problems, my personal suggestion is to start using GNU/Linux :)